# Web View Fragment html embeed video fullscreen suport

Tags: android, html, video, webview, fullscreen

Hello everyone i got a question regarding how to enable full screen support in html embed videos on my webview i have hardware accelerated true on manifest and the video works ok but wen pressed to go fullscreen the video stops.

here is my code

```
import com.photoshop.video.tutorials.R;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
public final static String TAG = WebViewFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private WebView viewContentWebView;
private String url;

private boolean resetHistory = true;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

final ProgressBar viewContentProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress);
viewContentWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
viewContentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
viewContentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,          String failingUrl) {
        viewContentWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

    }



@Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
  }
});
viewContentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    viewContentProgress.setProgress(newProgress);
    viewContentProgress.setVisibility(newProgress == 100 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

    if (newProgress == 100 && resetHistory) {
        viewContentWebView.clearHistory();
        resetHistory = false;
    }
  }
});
return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
reload();
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
if (hidden)
  viewContentWebView.stopLoading();
else
  reload();
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;

if (viewContentWebView != null)
  viewContentWebView.stopLoading();

resetHistory = true;
}

public void reload() {
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
  return;

viewContentWebView.loadUrl(url);
}

public boolean onBackPressed() {
if (viewContentWebView.canGoBack()) {
  viewContentWebView.goBack();
  return true;
}
return false;
}
}
```

How can i achieve this
many thanks in advance and a little  patience with me because i am very very VERY new to android

Answer (score 1):

You should override the two following methods in your WebChromeClient:

- public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback);
- public void onHideCustomView();

This is an extract of the code I'm using:

```
private View mCustomView;

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private int mOriginalOrientation;
        private FullscreenHolder mFullscreenContainer;
        private CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCollback;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {

            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mOriginalOrientation = mActivity.getRequestedOrientation();

            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();

            mFullscreenContainer = new FullscreenHolder(mActivity);
            mFullscreenContainer.addView(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            decor.addView(mFullscreenContainer, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCollback = callback;
            mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);

        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return;
            }

            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            decor.removeView(mFullscreenContainer);
            mFullscreenContainer = null;
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewCollback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // show the content view.

            mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);
        }


    static class FullscreenHolder extends FrameLayout {

        public FullscreenHolder(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```